# Sorting an ArrayList of String[] using multiple Indices

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I'm new to actively writing questions here, although I've used this site for some time now.

I want to sort an ArrayList in lexicalic order (= natural order?!) depending on the first two indices of the array. Currently I've used the code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String[]> workingSet = new ArrayList<>();
        workingSet.add(new String[]{"MiningCorp", "2265 Betacity"});
        workingSet.add(new String[]{"MiningCorp", "6454 Iotacity"});
        workingSet.add(new String[]{"Arbiter", "3812 Gammacity"});
        workingSet.add(new String[]{"MiningCorp", "1234 Thetacity"});
        workingSet.add(new String[]{"Arbiter", "1812 Deltacity"});

        Comparator<String[]> staComp = new Comparator<String[]>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String[] first, String[] second) {
                String composite1 = first[0] + " " + first[1];
                String composite2 = second[0] + " " + second[1];
                return composite1.compareTo(composite2);
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(workingSet, staComp);
        for(String[] arr : workingSet){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }


    }

}
```

This should produce the following output:

```
[Arbiter, 1812 Deltacity]
[Arbiter, 3812 Gammacity]
[MiningCorp, 1234 Thetacity]
[MiningCorp, 2265 Betacity]
[MiningCorp, 6454 Iotacity]
```

This exactly what I wanted. 
Is there a more elegant way using prebuilt methods?

What if I wanted to sort by grouping by the first array entry in lexicalic order, but within this group i want the individual arrays to be sorted by inverse lexicalic order?
For this, do I need a second comparator to first pre-sort the entries of the second index of each array?

Here is what i want to get for this example:

```
[Arbiter, 3812 Gammacity]
[Arbiter, 1812 Deltacity]
[MiningCorp, 6454 Iotacity]
[MiningCorp, 2265 Betacity]
[MiningCorp, 1234 Thetacity]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If java8 is an option, than I would use the `thenComparing` method to combine two sort specifiers.

When using `reversed` the result of a comparator will be upside down.

Example code:

```
// turn your list into a stream
workingSet.stream()

// sort it...
.sorted(

    // first sort specifier: 0th element of Array
    Comparator.<String[], String>comparing(composite -> composite[0])

        // combine sort specifiers
        .thenComparing(

                // second sort specifier: 2st element of Array
                Comparator.<String[], String>comparing(composite -> composite[1])

                // REVERSED!
                .reversed()
        )
    )

// convert each array to a String
.map(Arrays::toString)

// print each String
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

> What if I wanted to sort by grouping by the first array entry in lexicalic order, but within this group i want the individual arrays to be sorted by inverse lexicalic order?

Then you'll need to implement the `Comparator` differently:

```
Comparator<String[]> secondComparator = new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] first, String[] second) {
            int compareFirstPart = first[0].compareTo(second[0]);
            if(compareFirstPart != 0)
                return compareFirstPart;
            else
                return second[1].compareTo(first[1]); // Inverse!
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use java 8, you may use lambda expressions as well :

```
Collections.sort(workingSet, (first, second) -> {
            int compareFirstPart = first[0].compareTo(second[0]);
            if(compareFirstPart != 0)
                return compareFirstPart;
            else
                return second[1].compareTo(first[1]); 
});
```

Comment: while lambda expressions are not entirely new for me, this makes it clearer for me how they work in java. Thank you for your answer.